# Elastic search sort error - search_phase_execution_exception

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, opensearch

I am facing an issue with sorting values in an elastic search query. I am doing a simple search with sort but getting the following error. The query works without a sort parameter.

Elastic search client version: **Version 7.6.1**(Using this version because I am using opensearch)

> search_phase_execution_exception: [illegal_argument_exception] Reason:
> Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document
> field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are
> disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead.
> Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [subtype] in order to load field
> data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use
> significant memory.

Code Sample:

```
const {Client} = require('@elastic/elasticsearch') // Version 7.6.1
var connectionString = 'https://admin:admin@localhost:9200'
const client = new Client({
    node: connectionString,
    ssl: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
})
client.info()
    .then(async response => {
        console.log('success', response.statusCode)
        var query = {
            "query": {
                "match": {
                    "revhostname": {
                        "query": "ten.tsacmoc.ac.1dsh.631-651-14-37-c",
                    },
                },
            },
            "sort": [
                {
                    "revhostname": {"order": "asc"},
                    "subtype": {"order": "asc"},
                    "value": {"order": "asc"},
                }
            ],
        };
        var response = await client.search({
            index: 'r7',
            body: query,
        });
        console.log("Search results:", JSON.stringify(response));
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('error', JSON.stringify(error))
    })
```

Mapping:

```
{
     "properties": {
       "revhostname": {
         "type" : "keyword"
       },
       "value": {
         "type" : "keyword"
       },
       "subtype": {
         "type" : "keyword"
       },
       "timestamp": {
         "type" : "long"
       },
       "ip": {
         "type" : "ip"
       }
     }
   }
```

I tried adding fielddata=true in mapping but the issue was not solved. Your help is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you reindexed all the docs after updating the mapping? Also, is this the actual mapping that you're getting from `GET /INDEX/_mapping`?

Comment: Not reindexed after mapping. I am getting mapping like following GET /INDEX/_mapping

    "revhostname": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned mapping in a comment, your `revhostname` field is defined as `text` and `keyword` both type of field and Elasticsearch dont allow sorting on `text` type of field.

If your mapping is still same as you mentioned in comment then you need to use the field name like `revhostname.keyword` which will resolved issue.

```
const {Client} = require('@elastic/elasticsearch') // Version 7.6.1
var connectionString = 'https://admin:admin@localhost:9200'
const client = new Client({
    node: connectionString,
    ssl: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
})
client.info()
    .then(async response => {
        console.log('success', response.statusCode)
        var query = {
            "query": {
                "match": {
                    "revhostname": {
                        "query": "ten.tsacmoc.ac.1dsh.631-651-14-37-c",
                    },
                },
            },
            "sort": [
                {
                    "revhostname.keyword": {"order": "asc"},
                    "subtype.keyword": {"order": "asc"},
                    "value.keyword": {"order": "asc"},
                }
            ],
        };
        var response = await client.search({
            index: 'r7',
            body: query,
        });
        console.log("Search results:", JSON.stringify(response));
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('error', JSON.stringify(error))
    })
```